# Strange memory corruption in C

Tags: c, clang

In answering another question I wrote up what should be some simple code to initialize and print a 2D array. But something very strange is happening.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print_row( const int *row, size_t num_cols ) {
    printf("%p\n", (void*)row);
    for( size_t col_num = 0; col_num < num_cols; col_num++ ) {
        printf(" %2d ", row[col_num]);
    }
    puts("");
}

int **make_board( const size_t num_rows, const size_t num_cols ) {
    int **board = malloc( sizeof(int) * num_rows );

    for( size_t row_num = 0; row_num < num_rows; row_num++ ) {
        int *row = calloc( num_cols, sizeof(int) );
        board[row_num] = row;
        print_row(row, num_cols);
    }

    return board;
}

void print_board( int **board, const size_t num_rows, const size_t num_cols ) {
    for( size_t row_num = 0; row_num < num_rows; row_num++ ) {
        const int *row = board[row_num];
        print_row(row, num_cols);
    }
}

int main() {
    size_t num_rows = 6;
    size_t num_cols = 4;
    puts("Making the board");
    int **board = make_board(num_rows, num_cols);
    puts("Printing the board");
    print_board(board, num_rows, num_cols);
}
```

Running it, I occasionally get one corrupted row, but only ever in `print_board` never in `make_board`.

```
cc -Wall -Wshadow -Wwrite-strings -Wextra -Wconversion -std=c99 -pedantic -g   -c -o test.o test.c
cc   test.o   -o test

Making the board
0x7fc4e6d00370
  0   0   0   0 
0x7fc4e6d001e0
  0   0   0   0 
0x7fc4e6d001f0
  0   0   0   0 
0x7fc4e6d00200
  0   0   0   0 
0x7fc4e6d00210
  0   0   0   0 
0x7fc4e6d00220
  0   0   0   0 
Printing the board
0x7fc4e6d00370
  0   0   0   0 
0x7fc4e6d001e0
 -422575600  32708  -422575584  32708 
0x7fc4e6d001f0
  0   0   0   0 
0x7fc4e6d00200
  0   0   0   0 
0x7fc4e6d00210
  0   0   0   0 
0x7fc4e6d00220
  0   0   0   0
```

If I link in packages, like glib-2, the corruption happens more frequently.

```
cc -Wall -Wshadow -Wwrite-strings -Wextra -Wconversion -std=c99 -pedantic -g `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0`   -c -o test.o test.c
cc `pkg-config --libs glib-2.0`   test.o   -o test
```

The memory locations are all correct. All rows are fine during initialization. There's no compiler warnings. `-fsanitize=address` finds no errors.

What might be causing that one row to become corrupted? Can anyone even repeat the problem?

```
$ cc --version
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

$ uname -a
Darwin Windhund.local 17.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 17.6.0: Tue May  8 15:22:16 PDT 2018; root:xnu-4570.61.1~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 i386 MacBookPro8,1 Darwin
```

Comment: `int **board = malloc( sizeof(int) * num_rows );`-->`int **board = malloc( sizeof(int *) * num_rows );`

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Thanks, 4 vs 8, that would do it. Put that in an answer and I'll accept. Strange `-fsanitize=address` didn't catch it.

Comment: Simple rule: 1 less `*` in the `sizeof` argument than the type of the pointer.

Comment: There are already hundreds of similar questions, not much point in answering this one.

Comment: @Barmar an even simpler rule is to use `sizeof *variable_name`

Comment: @Schwern In case you are unaware, you can use a single allocation pointed to by `int (*)[num_cols]`, instead of using one allocation per row

Comment: @M.M Yes, I know, I didn't want to complicate my comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are allocating your array of int pointers as an array of ints resulting in some unexpected behavior.  Simple enough fix, fortunately.

Replace this line:

```
int **board = malloc( sizeof(int) * num_rows );
```

With this line:

```
int **board = malloc( sizeof(int *) * num_rows );
```

Or, to avoid these kind of mistakes in the future, as pointed out by Jonathan Leffler below in the comments, you can perform the `sizeof` operator on the dereferenced variable you are trying to allocate so you don't have to worry about getting the type correct:

```
int **board = malloc( sizeof(*board) * num_rows );
```

Comment: Or, better in some ways, `int **board = malloc(sizeof(*board) * num_rows);`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ah, yes, that notation would have avoided the problem in the first place..